# Android studio: expanding and deflating circle animation

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-animation, android-xml

I'm trying to create a circle in android studio which expands and deflates. I only want to use one Java class and a layout xml file. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: usually people show some code of what they have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
If you wanted to create circle, there one way  I could suggest you create an oval shape.

First create an XML file in your drawable package right-click on it and select a new resource file, give a name to that file let's suppose bg_circle.

```
    <shape android:shape="oval" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
     <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="2dp"/>

    </shape>
```

This will create an oval, you may change the colors as you want from your color.xml file.
Now, what you need to do is that you have to add an attribute in your imageView which is

```
      android: src = "@drawable/bg_circle".
```

If you do not need the outline of the circle you can remove the stroke color from bg_circle.xml

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.
One Option is using an ImageView inside a CardView in your xml layout, and animate that, here is a minimal example with a black circle :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_round"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">  // -> this makes it look circular

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Note that this is not really a circle, it just looks like one.

Once you cast the CardView in your Java code :

```
CardView cardViewCircular = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv_round);
```

the expand/deflate animation is a one liner with [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) f.e. (expanding 50f) :

```
cardViewCircular.animate().scaleYBy(50f).scaleXBy(50f); //deflating is -50f
```

or use the scaleX(50f) / scaleY(50f) methods, whichever suits you better.